# Using Java, how to work with binary data furnished as string in this notation: b'\x00@\xfftest\x0d\n\x00'

Tags: java, string, encoding, binary

`b'\x00@\xfftest\x0d\n\x00'`
I've got a .csv file where one of the columns is binary data encoded to a string with a hybrid of ascii, control characters and escaped hex.

Can you tell me the formal name for this notation/encoding, and is there a Java class for converting such a string to byte[], and for converting byte[] to a string in this format?

Comment: Use something like [THIS](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html#decodeHex(java.lang.String)) maybe

Comment: Looks a lot like a Python [bytes literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).

Comment: I don't know if my memory is playing tricks on me, but I think back in the day Java used to support hex literals...
My first comment is only partially useful - it won't cope with a 'mixed string'. The whole string has to be hex-escaped

Comment: I’m guessing Java has support, but many searches haven’t turned up the class. Hence asking for the exact name.  It’s reminiscent of printf syntax.  I know I can paste this into Python as a bytes literal, but that’s no help.  This isn’t hex, it’s a scheme to represent all 256 octets with printable characters.    Thanks for your comments but still looking.

Comment: Well, `\x00` looks very much like hex for the null character to me, `\x0d` the newline character

Comment: More examples might be good

Comment: You asked for the formal name of the encoding.  The formal name for it is a Python bytes literal.  I guess if any library is doing to deal with it, it would be a Python parser.  Though it didn’t take me terribly long to write one from scratch.  (Not a general Python parser of course, just a Python bytes literal parser.)

Comment: Thanks, VGR. I was just expecting the Python bytes literal to be a multi language standard that Python adopted.  I can write a parser in not to terribly long time, too.  I didn’t want to because it would be inelegant to not use an existing package, not because it’s hard.  Would have been simpler if whoever implemented the data recorder had made the field a straight hex dump.

Comment: Agreed.  Storing binary data using a Python syntax seems like one of the worst options possible.  I wonder if perhaps the code that wrote the file didn’t even try to translate the data or serialize it at all, and just dumped the field regardless of its type.

Comment: The format makes sense in a way: it's basically translating control chars into hex and leaving printing characters alone. The problem is that this mixing makes it harder to parse than if it were all encoded in some way

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer myself, here's what I can find: Because the format of the strings in the CSV file are the Python bytes literal, there's no reason to expect a canned Java implementation.  In the mean time, thanks to commenters I was able to figure out how to do the straightforward conversions in Python so I can implement a parser in Python for now.

The conversions are

```
import ast
originalbytes=b'\x00\xffTest\n\x00'
print('Bytes literal:',databytes)
print('Bytes list:   ',list(databytes))
datastring=str(originalbytes)
print('String:       ',datastring)
restoredbytes=ast.literal_eval(datastring)
print('Bytes list:   ',list(restoredbytes))
```

```
Bytes literal:b'\x00\xffTest\n\x00' 
Bytes list:   [0, 255, 84, 101, 115, 116, 10, 0] 
String:       b'\x00\xffTest\n\x00' 
Bytes list:   [0, 255, 84, 101, 115, 116, 10, 0]
```

The puzzling but fortuitous behavior is that the str() function (*without* specifying encoding) is the only way to get the type bytes object to convert to a type string object. If I specify encoding such as utf-8, ascii or ISO-8859-1 in the str() function or attempt to use databytes.decode(), errors occur when encountering the hex numbers, e.g. *codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)*.